# How to display recent posts on home page with title, post date, author and featured image?

Tags: post-thumbnails, homepage, recent-posts

I am looking to display some undecided number of recent posts (no more than 5) on my home page banner. For each post, I would like to display the title, post date, author and a featured images as background for thumbnail of the content.

I was wondering what are the WordPress functions to get this. I would also like to custom format the HTML. The closest I have gotten is looks like this

```
<?php    
<!-- Post carousel -->
            <div class="cs-post-carousel-layout">
                <div class="cs-container swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <?php

    // define query arguments
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 8, // your 'x' goes here
        'nopaging' => true
        // possibly more arguments here
    );

    // set up new query
    $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // loop through found posts
    while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) : $tyler_query->the_post();
                        //Post item -->
                        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">'.
                            '<div class="cs-post-item">'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-category-icon">'.
                                    '<a href="'.
                                    get_permalink().
                                    '"></i></a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-thumb">'.
                                    '<a href="post_standard.html"><img src="demo/carousel/1.jpg" alt="UniqMag"></a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-inner">'.
                                    '<h3><a href="'.
                                    get_permalink().
                                    '">'.
                                    get_the_title().
                                    '</a></h3>'.
                                    //'<div class="cs-post-meta cs-clearfix">'.
                                       // '<span class="cs-post-meta-author"><a href="post_standard.html">J. Doe</a></span>'.
                                       // '<span class="cs-post-meta-date">Sep 19, 2015</span>'.
                                    //'</div>'.
                                '</div>'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>';
                        endwhile;

    // reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what is the question? it is hard to just look at the code and understand what is the "problem" with it if it is not spelled out

Comment: @MarkKaplun I think the question is to convert the static HTML links and stuff to dynamically generated values of the post by WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

The functions you are looking for, are:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url(); // For featured image
the_author(); // For author name
get_author_posts_url(); // For author link
the_date(); // For post's date
```

So, your code should be something like this:

```
<div class="cs-post-carousel-layout">
    <div class="cs-container swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper"><?php

            // define query arguments
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5, // your 'x' goes here
                'nopaging' => true
                // possibly more arguments here
            );

            // set up new query
            $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // loop through found posts
            if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
                while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $tyler_query->the_post();
                    //Post item -->
                    ?><div class="swiper-slide">
                        <div class="cs-post-item">
                            <div class="cs-post-category-icon">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cs-post-thumb">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cs-post-inner">
                                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                                <div class="cs-post-meta cs-clearfix">
                                   <span class="cs-post-meta-author"><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID'));?>"><?php the_author();?></a></span>
                                   <span class="cs-post-meta-date"><?php the_date();?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><?php
                }
            }
            // reset post data
            wp_reset_postdata();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also reformatted your HTML code for you, and added indentation.

Comment: Thank you it works fine, but i am not able to link image with the permalink, is there any issue there?

Comment: @J.Lee You are welcome. Do you mean that you want your images to be clickable?

Comment: Yes, that's true. I want images to be clickable.

Comment: @J.Lee But i already did that for you. Look at the line after `<div class="cs-post-thumb">`. There might be a CSS issue that makes the clickable area small enough that you can't click. Otherwise, the code does what you asked.